# Combining multiple 'AND' with 'LIKE' statements in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause, sql-like

Building a basic search tool in PostgreSQL.

When I setup a basic query like below I receive data.

```
SELECT *
FROM schema_name.table_name
WHERE column_name1 = 'sometext' AND column_name2 LIKE '%sometext%'
;
```

But when I and more conditions to the where clause like below, the query does execute, but I receive no data.

```
SELECT *
FROM schema_name.table_name
WHERE column_name1 = 'sometext' AND column_name2 LIKE '%sometext%' AND column_name3 = 'somemoretext'
;
```

I've tested individual queries to ensure there are records that meet all of the conditions and they exist. However I cannot find a way to tie the criteria together into one query. Most examples I've seen online stop at two conditions or do not combine 'AND' with 'LIKE'. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

-Edit 1 Begins Here-

Sample Query that generates no data in PostgreSQL

```
SELECT *
FROM ctgov.studies
WHERE (overall_status = 'Recruiting') AND (official_title LIKE '%immunotherapy%') AND (source LIKE '%university%')
;
```

When I execute the same search via the website I gather data for the DB it returns 163 matching records. Using 'OR' in this scenario would retrieve records that won't match all the criteria I'm looking for.

Comment: Please provide some sample data und expected output.

Comment: Just because you found three sets of records which meet one of the conditions does not mean that any records meet all three conditions.  Please add sample data.

Comment: Every time you add another condition using `AND` you redduce the number of matching rows, since your query become stricter. Use `OR` instead if you want to search for *any* of them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `OR` instead `AND`

```
  SELECT *
    FROM schema_name.table_name
    WHERE column_name1 = 'sometext' OR column_name2 LIKE '%sometext%' OR column_name3 = 'somemoretext'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone, learned that my queries were too strict and I did not account for capitalization in text recognition.